# Huge Banner.. What size to make artwork in?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, file-size, outdoors

I have to make artwork for a banner that is 123'' X 194''. 
I am not sure what size to make the page I am creating the artwork on in Photoshop. It obviously doesn't let me make it that big. Do I need to make it into CM or MM? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD. I think this will answer your question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/487/what-resolution-should-a-large-format-artwork-for-print-be

Comment: See also: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should

Comment: I'll also shamelessly plug: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/how-do-i-figure-out-the-right-size-font-text-for-a-given-read-distance

Answer (score 0):

**I can.** What *version* of Photoshop are you using?

Note that the size mentioned at 300 DPI is **6GB** in size, so that's pretty large. *Also, I  get a notice (using CS4) that it may not be compatible with older versions of PS. That might be your issue.*

Personally, I would "create" the graphic in Illustrator if you have it (or at least the smaller parts of it).

To answer the actual question: **You need to *(should)* make it the size of what you need it, so 123in x 194in @ 300dpi would be your best bet for maximum quality.**

Comment: I highly doubt a banner that size is going to be viewed at a distance where 300dpi is required. Typically for artwork that large, 100dpi is more than enough.

Comment: **"for maximum quality"**. The (I'm assuming vinyl) printer may only print at 100dpi - it's really something the OP should check with the printer about.

Comment: even then if it is only one color lettering and a distance, 75dpi would work.