# "Print size" & "Distance from viewer" requires "What font size?"

Tags: print-design, font-size

I have always selected my font size by the eye or educated guess/trial and error but at this point I would like to know where I could find a chart or document with guidelines regarding **what font size you should use** for **this print size** considering the viewer will see it from **this distance**.

---

While the suggested "[Duplicate Question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/how-do-i-figure-out-the-right-size-font-text-for-a-given-read-distance)" might have some nice details, as far as I saw from the question and answers, this only targets Street Signs while taking into account car speed limit. This is only a branch of what my question is about.

I am interested in a more general way, a rule of thumbs of some sort that will help you get an idea on how to design something from A4 posters to outdoor billboards.

Comment: Great question! :o)

Comment: I believe I came across an equation for the reading distance of signs somewhere online but I've never been able to find it again.

Comment: @johnp Something like that would really come in handy. There are times when you could really use an equation of some sort to reassure yourself of your design.

Comment: @Alin As far as road signage is concerned, road authorities may have guidelines for typesetting those (usually for some sort of DIN variant), but I think other scenarios/fonts will have too many variables to work with...

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/how-do-i-figure-out-the-right-size-font-text-for-a-given-read-distance

Comment: @johnp Unfortunately, in my country they don't. There are some other advertising companies that have some mockups with guidelines for their own rental billboards though but they don't share, as one might expect :D Anyway, I voted to reopen the question as I am not interested only in road signs but in a more general manner. Added some more details in the question.

Comment: @Alin the duplicate isn't about signage at all, only one of the answers talk about signage because that's where you'll find most research on this; the question and other answers are all more general and don't even mention signs. Don't get me wrong this is a great question, I just don't see how it's any different.