# Proper term for a font with the same thickness for all strokes?

Tags: font-recommendation, style-identification, terminology

I'm looking at placing numbers on sports equipment and need a font with numbers that maintain the same parallel width or thickness for each digit.

I mean uniform width of the line that makes up the actual ink of the figure. I don't mean the actual width of the characters from start to finish, I mean the inner and outer edges of the font. I don't mean tabular figures. Tabular means the space the numbers occupy is identical. Can anyone suggest any please? Many thanks

[image: German number-plate digits]

[image: UK number-plate digits]

They all have to be a uniform 45mm. So for example on a number 4, the upright and horizontal and diagonal line all have to be 45mm. Do you see?

On most fonts the different lines or curves of the numbers are slightly thicker or thinner.

What term should be used when searching for a font of this nature?

Comment: It's only 10 digits. May be easier to draw your own numbers.

Comment: There's no specific term for this, but some terms that might help would be 'monoline', 'low contrast', or, based on your example of the 8, 'LCD'. Alas, there's no one right answer to this question, so I don't think it's a suitable SE question. I would suggest taking those search terms to MyFonts.com to find a whole bunch of options, though.

Comment: Hi,  yes User 568458 - you are exactly right - I mean uniform weight throughout for every number. So no typographic contrast. I can't actually draw it for reasons too complicated to explain right now, sorry. But yes I think you understand.

Comment: I've added images. The bottom one is from UK car number plates; you may be able to find such a font online, and probably free.

Comment: @Scott the edit makes this a duplicate question. Give me a minute to find the duplicate...

Comment: Here it is: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37501/term-for-fonts-with-fixed-versus-variable-stroke-widths

Comment: Good point @DA01 I just felt the nature of "find a font for me" a bad precedent to set. Perhaps this should just be closed as a duplicate? It is essentially asking the same thing. My edit just made it less of a "Google for me" question.

Comment: @Scott yea, I'd call it a duplicate. Essentially asking the same thing: What terms do I need to find the font I want on MyFonts? :)

Answer (score 3):

The fonts designed for drafting (technical lettering) have this property as they were standardized for technical pens that make uniform lines.  You can find some of these by searching for isofont. Theres even a nice open source version with really broad implementation called [osifont](http://code.google.com/p/osifont/).

Fontforge allows you o make these fonts out of unclosed lines so you can change thickness later if you need to.

Several variations of iso and asme standard fonts, exist ive even made my own when i happened to be cut of from most of humanity and had no suitable font with the specific glyph i needed ( made the fonts with notepad).

Answer (score 2):

In general, searching almost *any* font service for words like `athletic`, `college`, `jersey`, and `sports` will often turn up many options. This is due to the nature of usage, which is often close to what you seem to be in need of as well.

Other common terms may be Slab Serif or Monoline depending upon your actual desired appearance.

A few suggestions:

- [Yearbook Solid](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/yearbook-outline/yearbook-solid/)
- [Undergrad](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/thomas-kaeding/undergrad/)
- [YWTF League](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ywft/ywft-league/extra-bold/)
- [Industry Inc](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fort-foundry/industry-inc/base/)
- [Player](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/canadatype/player/black/)
- [Ringo](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typoland/ringo/black/)
- [Gin](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fort-foundry/gin/regular/)
- [Prohibition](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fort-foundry/prohibition/regular/)

Answer (score 1):

The first type of font that comes to mind for sports jerseys and equipment is a "college" style font. dafont has a lot of this available for free under the [Old School](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=104&text=1234567890) category, or just search for "[college](http://www.dafont.com/search.php?text=1234567890&q=college)". Here are a few that seem to meed your criteria:

#### [Jersey M54](http://www.dafont.com/jersey-m54.font?text=1234567890&back=theme)

[image: Jersey M54 font sample]

#### [Allstar](http://www.dafont.com/allstar.font?text=1234567890&back=theme)

[image: Allstar font sample]

#### [Varsity](http://www.dafont.com/varsity-regular.font?text=1234567890&psize=l&back=theme)

[image: Varsity font sample]

If you're looking for a different style, consider browsing the [monoline tag on MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Amonoline/fonts/) or search for [sports jersey](http://www.myfonts.com/search/sports+jersey/fonts/). One of the first results for me is more of a "Euro" style but would look nice on the back of a jersey.

#### [YWFT Unisect](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ywft/unisect/)

[image: YWFT Unisect font sample]

Answer (score -1):

Fixed Width Font is what it's called

Comment: Sorry, when I hear fixed width it normally means all the characters are the same width, normally called a monospace font. That's not what this is about.