# CharterBT/CMSans complementary monospaced font

Tags: fonts, typography, typefaces, typesetting, latex

I am writing a technical documentation in LaTeX which will also include code listings and in-text keywords set in Monospace. After reading [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51/what-font-types-are-good-for-a-technical-document) i chose a combination of CharterBT for text and Computer Modern Sans Serif Bold for headings.

Charter:
[image]

Computer Modern Sans Bold:
[image]

However I do not like the default monospaced font of LaTeX, mainly because it looks way to fancy or old to me.

Which monospaced font is complementary to the fonts I am using?

Note that I can not use any font that is not [available in my LaTex distribution](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "the default monospaced font" are you referring to the monospace counterpart to Computer Modern?

[image]

If so, I think you're responding to the Prestige Elite-style serif treatment, which is so retro it's almost fashionable these days ;)

The complicating factor is that you've chosen a proportional sans face that is very similar in style to sanserif monospace faces. You may have to use a variation in size, color, or weight to help differentiate the two.

I would experiment with these faces from your available set, in order of my guess at compatibility.

**Bera Mono**

[image]

**Droid Sans Mono**

[image]

**DejaVu Sans Mono**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that all heading are set in bold letters. I have changed my question.

Comment: No problem. That doesn't change my recommendations.